# shiro pac4j cas ajax 401 when accessing another client

Tags: single-sign-on, cas, shiro, pac4j

I am using cas 5.x.

I have `cas-server` and two web apps `client-1` and `client-2`.

currently, I can single sign on and single sign out, but there is one problem in following steps:

1. access `client-1`, it will ask me for login in cas server, then redirect me back to `client-1` after login success.
2. click one button to access the protected resources of `client-2` via `ajax` in page of `client-1`, however this ajax call return `401`.

if i access protected resources of `client-2` from browser address bar directly in `step 2`, it works.

ajax cannot handle the redirect cause this problem, thus how to solve this problem?

my ajax call is :

```
//test() is in client-1
function test() {
            
    jQuery.ajax({
        url:"http://192.168.0.14:8445/client-2/user/userInfo",
        headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},        
        success: function(res) {                    
            //...
        }        
    });
        
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the ajax call you make? Also provide the exact error message.

Comment: @leopal plz see the bottom of post to see my ajax call, and there is no error message, just said `401` for this ajax call. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Per the pac4j documentation,

> When you're using an Indirect Client, if the user tries to access a protected URL, the request will be redirected to the identity provider for login. Though, if the incoming HTTP request is an AJAX one, no redirection will be performed and a 401 error page will be returned.

So what you're seeing is expected behavior.

Next, the HTTP request is considered to be an AJAX one if the value of the `X-Requested-With` header is `XMLHttpRequest` or if the `is_ajax_request` parameter or header is `true`. This is the default behavior/condition when handling/detecting AJAX requests, and by default, pac4j will only compute the redirection URL and add it as a header (assuming the `addRedirectionUrlAsHeader`  is set to true for the indirect client) when it passes back the 401 http status.

> ajax cannot handle the redirect cause this problem

It's not designed to handle the redirects. You need to catch the 401 in your AJAX call, take the redirect url from the header that is passed back to you and do the redirect yourself automatically, or do any other activity/action that is correct behavior for your application (display message, redirect to another URL, etc).

Comment: i caught the 401 in ajax call, and the response header is `https://localhost:8443/cas/login?service=http://192.168.0.14/client-2/callback?client_name=pac4j2Client`, i manually call this header url then call original url, still get 401.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i'll try to find the solution according what you said.